# Is there any way to compress the data while using mongo persistence with NEventStore?

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, compression, event-sourcing, neventstore

I'm working with C#, Dotnet core, and [NeventStore](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/wiki)( version- 9.0.1), trying to evaluate various persistence options that it supports out of the box.

More specifically, when trying to use the mongo persistence, the payload is getting stored ***without any compression*** being applied.

**Note: Payload compression is happening perfectly when using the SQL persistence of NEventStore whereas not with the mongo persistence.**

I'm using the below code to create the event store and initialize:

```
    private IStoreEvents CreateEventStore(string connectionString) 
    { 
        var store = Wireup.Init() 
                        .UsingMongoPersistence(connectionString,  
                             new NEventStore.Serialization.DocumentObjectSerializer()) 
                        .InitializeStorageEngine() 
                        .UsingBsonSerialization() 
                        .Compress() 
                        .HookIntoPipelineUsing() 
                        .Build(); 
        return store; 
    }
```

And, I'm using the below code for storing the events:

```
public async Task AddMessageTostore(Command command) 
{ 
    using (var stream = _eventStore.CreateStream(command.Id)) 
         { 
                stream.Add(new EventMessage { Body = command }); 
                stream.CommitChanges(Guid.NewGuid()); 
         }
}
```

**The workaround did:** *Implementing the PreCommit(CommitAttempt attempt) and Select methods in IPipelineHook and by using gzip compression logic the compression of events was achieved in MongoDB.*

Attaching data store image of both SQL and mongo persistence:
[image]

[image]

So, the questions are:

1. Is there some other option or setting I'm missing so that the events get compressed while saving(fluent way of calling compress method) ?
2. Is the workaround mentioned above sensible to do or is it a performance overhead?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue while using the **NEventStore.Persistence.MongoDB**.

Even if I used the fluent way of compress method, the payload compression is not happening perfectly in the mongo persistence like SQL persistence.
Finally, I have achieved the compression/decompression by customizing the logic inside the **PreCommit(CommitAttempt attempt)** and **Select(ICommit committed)** methods.

**Code used for compression:**

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      using (var compressedStream = new GZipStream(stream,
                                              CompressionMode.Compress))
        {

           var serializer = new JsonSerializer { 
                           TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None, 
                           ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
           };
           
           var writer = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(compressedStream));
           serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
           writer.Flush();
      }
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

**Code used for decompression:**

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
 {
    var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer {  
                            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None, 
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
    };
    
   var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(decompressedStream));
   var body = serializer.Deserialize(reader, type);
   return body as Command;
}
```

*I'm not sure if this a right approach or will this have any impact on the performance of EventStore operations like Insert and Select.*.